# jQuery Plugin which displays a playlist (and play songs)?

Tags: jquery

Near the bottom of this site: http://love-detroit.com/ the is a Listen block.

It displays music using jQuery, I think it doesn't use flash (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Is there a jQuery plugin similar to that one?

Comment: It must use flash or a similar plug-in (Silverlight, Java Applet). There is no way to do so via JavaScript. Typically, jQuery plugins that have these types of capabilities have a very minimal and tiny swf that it uses for its core.

Comment: @Kris It used to be that Flash was or a similar plug-in was the only way you could have an audio player.  With browsers that support HTML5, it's now done with either the HTML5 <audio> or <video> elements.  For compatibility, most of these new HTML5 Audio/Video APIs/Frameworks fall back to Flash if the browser doesn't support HTML5.

Comment: @Jazzerus in my opinion, HTML5 isn't wide spread enough to even be worth looking into for these controls (though, I did try to add it to my original list but my time ran out for editing =/). If a solid control can use it then great but I would be wary about differing behaviors at this stage should it use HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you view the source, you'll see it's a combination of JavaScript with HTML5 (which falls back to Flash for older browsers).  It's based off of this API/framework:

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

and this jQuery plugin for the UI/controls:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/playable

Answer (score 0):

It is not flash..

Its HTML 5...

```
<video controls="" autoplay="" style="margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;" name="media" src="http://love-detroit.com/mp3/01%20What%20Child%20is%20This.mp3"></video>
```

Comment: So its HTML5. Is flash going extinct?

Comment: No, definitely not. Flash still provides far more abilities than HTML5. In fact, many content providers are avoiding HTML5 due to the lack of control over their video. Flash is going to be around for a very long time and HTML5 isn't even spec complete so it's unlikely to see it widely adopted for at least a few more years (though some are already adopting it for iPod / iPad / iPhone functionality).